# How can i detect if (float)0 == 0 or null in PHP

Tags: php, decimal, detect, zero

If variable value is 0 (float) it will pass all these tests:

```
    $test = round(0, 2); //$test=(float)0

    if($test == null)
        echo "var is null";
    if($test == 0)
        echo "var is 0";
    if($test == false)
        echo "var is false";
    if($test==false && $test == 0 && $test==null)
        echo "var is mixture";
```

I assumed that it will pass only if($test == 0)

Only solution I found is detect if $test is number using function is_number(), but can I detect if float variable equal zero?

Comment: Use `===` instead of `==`. That way you can compare data types as well

Comment: I tried but it will not pass if($test === 0)

Comment: http://3v4l.org/usPbP - Test againsts 0.0 or use is_float to check if it's a float or not first. Obviously `=== 0.0` is as fast as you're going to see.

Comment: If you test against zero imho this works the best:
if( round( $test, 1) === 0.0 ) { ... }

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Using `===` checks also for the datatype:

```
$test = round(0, 2); // float(0.00)

if($test === null) // false
if($test === 0) // false
if($test === 0.0) // true
if($test === false) // false
```

Comment: `0 == 0.0 && 0 !== 0.0` Floats and ints are non-comparable with triple equals.

Comment: Had trouble checking whether my float variable's value was 0 or null! This helped thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Use 3 equal signs rather than two to test the type as well:

```
if($test === 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use=== instead of == it will compare as well as get the data types errors manage...Can you post your answer while using === ? Please check the difference between this two [here](http://www.programmerinterview.com/index.php/php-questions/difference-between-and-in-php/)

> When comparing values in PHP for equality you can use either the == operator or the === operator. What’s the difference between the 2? Well, it’s quite simple. The == operator just checks to see if the left and right values are equal. But, the === operator (note the extra “=”) actually checks to see if the left and right values are equal, and also checks to see if they are of the same variable type (like whether they are both booleans, ints, etc.).